# The current path, auth/, didn't match any of these

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-urls

I am trying to setup url dispatcher in my project. I have project with follwing structure

```
forecast
|___ forecast
|_______ __init__.py
|_______ settings.py
|_______ urls.py
|_______ wsgi.py
|____authorization
|_______ apps.py
|_______ urls.py
|_______ models.py
|_______ views.py
|___ templates
|_______ registration
|____________ login.html
```

In my `forecast/urls.py` i put logic of

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path,include                                                                                     
urlpatterns = [
     path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
     path('',include('main.urls')),
     path('auth',
     include('authorization.urls')),
 ]
```

The main point for my question is  `path('auth',include('authorization.urls'))` i include urls.py from **authorization/** and in this urls.py i want to put all logic for authorization of my project like **login** page 
**registration** page **reset_password** page i have the following code in `authorization/urls.py`

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
      urlpatterns =[
            path('registration',
            views.registration_form),                
            path('login',
            views.login_name), 
      ]
```

My registration_form view is

```
from django.shortcuts import render
         def registration_form(request):
             return
             render(request,'registration/login.html',{})
```

For output my logic on front-end side i created in my project `templates` directory  and inside it `registration` directory and inside it i put `login.html` file. in settings.py i have

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [ 
    'django.contrib.admin',                                       
    'django.contrib.auth',                                     
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',                                
    'django.contrib.sessions',                                 
    'django.contrib.messages',                                 
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',                                 
    'dataflow',                                                    
    'authorization',                                           
    'main',                                                      
    'django.contrib.postgres',
 ]
  TEMPLATES = [{
    'DIRS':         
   [os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'templates')],
 }]
```

. Than after running server and opened `http://127.0.0.1:8000/auth/registration` but django erised `page not found` exception.Can anyone guide me where is error occured???

Comment: What's in "main.urls"?

Comment: @IainShelvington it is another app for my main page

Comment: The include for `main.urls` comes before the include for the auth urls. There could be something in it that is resolving to a 404 before the resolver gets to your urls

Comment: @IainShelvington i got the same error when replaced `main/urls.py` with `authorization/urls.py`

Comment: The actual error in the title is that there is no path "auth/", are you getting redirected there? Can you share `views.registration_form`?

Comment: @IainShelvington updated with adding registration_view code

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you included this segment in your `settings.py` ?

```py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    ...
    'authorization.apps.AuthorizationConfig',  // add this manually
]
```

The point is that, whenever you create an app, Django will not automatically register it as a part of the framework.

Comment: Sorry man but i have apps.py file which i didn't include in my described structure of my project. I was thinking that is didnt neccesary

Comment: So did this work after you add it into `INSTALLED_APPS`? Just asking

Comment: it was added to installed_apps i updated file with settings.py data forbetter understanding